# Picture Library export

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, picture-library

I have set up a picture library in SharePoint where you upload the image and fill in the fields about the image. Now what I'd like to do is be able to export/pull all of the images and all of the fields/information that go with that particular image for the entire picture library

Is this possible as users wnat to do the same export they do with lists.
Just the image on each column plus fields we do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no feature to export a picture library out of the box but you can develop a custom feature in VS 2010 and achieve this.

Have a look: http://mctalex.blogspot.in/2009/04/adding-export-to-spreadsheet-to-picture.html

Answer (score 0):

a simple trick to export pictures :

From your site, if you open a Library in explorer mode , You can list content files.

If now, from this view, you browse to the picture Library, you can list the pictures in a folder and you can copy them elsewhere.

Done for free and without any third party product like the designer.
It's working on my SharePoint 2010 foundation.
I hope it will works for you.